# PHP Conditional Questions Data Structure

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, tree

I'm working a webapp for a non-profit and I was wondering what would be the best data structure used to get the following effect:

The app will consist of obtaining information from a user, similar to the game 21 questions, but with more than Yes or No, for example I could ask the user a serious of 3 questions. Based on those answers there would be another set of X questions. This set of questions will be different depending on the answers of the first 3.

This would continue until the the app has figured out an answer.

Something like a tree with many branches perhaps.

Although I have limited experience in PHP and MySQL I'd like to be able to think of a structure that would be flexible enough to have many branches of the tree and many levels which ideally could be stored in a database or somewhere else.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We typically like to see examples and error messages on this side of SE, but, it would be rather convenient to store all those questions in a MySQL database. The algorithm would be different depending on how you want the questions to change.

You can arrange it so that each question on the screen has its own route, using ID to control the route:

- Question 1 (id 10) | Answer 1 (+10) | Answer 2 (+20) | Answer 3 (+30)
- Question 2 (id 11) | Answer 1 (+20) | Answer 2 (+10) | Answer 3 (+30)
- Question 3 (id 12) | Answer 1 (+20) | Answer 2 (+30) | Answer 3 (+10)

And if we say that the user picks 2|3|1:

- Question 4 (id 30)
- Question 5 (id 41)
- Question 6 (id 32)

Since the first digit is different and we're only incrementing in 10's, you won't run into any duplicate questions per run.

Another way would be explicitly defining the next question sets:

- Question 1 (id 1) | Answer 1 (5) | Answer 2 (12) | Answer 3 (9)
- Question 2 (id 2) | Answer 1 (7) | Answer 2 (16) | Answer 3 (18)
- Question 3 (id 3) | Answer 1 (4) | Answer 2 (10) | Answer 3 (24)

And again, user picks 2|3|1:

- Question 4 (id 12)
- Question 5 (id 18)
- Question 6 (id 4)

The rest of the application would just require you to run the query to pull the questions, keep track of the user data (get/post/session/mysql whathaveyou) and save the results to the db if that's what you wanted to do. AJAX would probably be pretty sweet to pull the next questions in after answering each set.

Comment: Hmm I suppose this is close enough that I'll mark it as the answer. My situation is more along the lines of something like. Answer to Q1, Q2, and Q3. Will either lead you to question 4, 5, 6 or 10,11,12.

This in turn could lead you to 15, 16,17. Etc.

Comment: Yep, that's the tough bit. Once you get the logic of how you want the next set of questions selected, it's a matter of devising the formula to achieve the results. I usually go for a point-based system, you can make it as simple or complex as you'd like, although I'd recommend keeping it simple. (KISS method)

Answer (score 0):

A common way to store tree data in a database is to add columns identyfing left and right neighbour and parent. CakePHP framework offers a way to easily manipulate data organised in a tree using [Tree Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html). Even if you don't want to use CakePHP, you can read the documentation to see how they implement it.