# Representing a set of conditional questinaires in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a webapp that will ask an end user a series of questions. Based on this, they will get another series/set of questions branching out into a tree.

So for example. The user is asked 2 questions:

Q1: How old are you?
   a)0 - 18
   b)18-35
   c)35-55
   d) 55+
Q2: Do you smoke?
   a) Yes
   b) No

if the user picks a|a they are asked a new set of questions, if they are asked a|b, they are asked another, and so on etc.

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to represent this in MySQL. The difficulty is mainly consolidating the fact that answer "a" to Q1 + answer "b" to Q2 goes to then next set of questions.

I've asked a similar question here:  [stackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056655/php-conditional-questions-data-structure).

But I wasn't happy with the result and it may have been my example so I've elaborated here.

Comment: I used all my `flag`s. OP gives DUPLICATE himself ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056655/php-conditional-questions-data-structure ...LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as "Routing" within the survey community.

The way I've implemented this into survey engines before is to have a full list of questions within a survey, which without any rules would let a user answer all the questions.

You then attach properties to each answer within a question, and then when each question is submitted, you check the properties of the selected answer, and see if it states whether to disable any future questions within the survey.

After this is done, you can then use a bit of logic along the lines of "GetNextQuestion()" which would check all the rules the respondent has amounted (ie which questions are disabled), and then display the next available question for them to answer.

It's a complicated process, both from a technical and admin perspective.

The database structure would involve a Questions table, an Answers table, and then an a AnswerDisablesQuestion table which would hold the AnswerID, and the questionID's that answer disables.

Comment: Are you aware of any bits of software that I can use to to create such a survey for use on my webapp or website?

Comment: https://www.surveymonkey.com/ is a popular one, although it's a hosted solution. Paid surveys is a fairly big industry, so you probably won't find too many comprehensive open source solutions.